# Breaking a foreach vs condition check in for

Tags: c#, loops, coding-style

In terms of better coding practices, which is a better decision?

1. using a `break` in a foreach to jump out of the loop
2. Using a condition check in a for loop to end the loop

So for example with a foreach:

```
foreach(string bean in stringArray)
{
    if(bean == "green")
    {
        break;
    }
}
```

And an example with a for loop:

```
bool found = false;
for (int i = 0; i < stringArray.Length && !found; i++)
{
    if (stringArray[i] == "green")
    {
        found = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: The break example is simpler to read and understand, so is the better option here. As Servy's answer shows though, with LinQ, there's often an even simpler way of looping over a set of values: let the framework do it for you.

Comment: The problem with LINQ: requires .NET 3.5+. If you are stuck in a pre-LINQ .NET (2.0, 3.0), then LINQ is not acceptable. From a semantics standpoint: the `break` option is much more readable and easily understood. A quick glance shows that when `bean` is `green`, then the loop terminates. This can still be done with a `for` loop, which tends to be the better practice if you don't *absolutely* require an instanced variable. (I.e. the `bean` variable.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just abstract away the mechanism entirely into another method.

(In this case, .NET already has such a method, so you don't need to write one.)

If you want to determine if there is any item meeting this condition:

```
var found = stringArray.Any(bean => bean == "green");
```

If you want to get all of the items until the condition is met:

```
var query = stringArray.TakeWhile(bean => bean != "green");
```

or if you just want to act on each of said items:

```
foreach(var bean in stringArray.TakeWhile(bean => bean != "green"))
{

}
```

Comment: I assume the TakeWhile is for an ordered type of collection such as an Array or LinkedList?

Comment: The only issue with this method is the dependence on LINQ and .NET 3.5+.

Comment: @Justin It's an extension method for `IEnumerable<T>`, which can be implemented by an ordered or unordered collection.

Comment: I have to tell the truth... I various years of LINQ programming, I've seen the `TakeWhile` used only a handful of times... It is one of those things that you see and think "aaaand"?

Comment: @EBrown I made a specific point of saying that, from a design standpoint, the idea here is to separate the mechanism of operations such as "give me all of the items until you hit one meeting this condition" from business logic that acts on those items.  It's easy enough to write your own implementations of these mechanisms if needed, particularly if you're not making the operations quite as robust and general purpose as the LINQ implementations (although at this point the number of people on .NET 2.0- are pretty small).

Comment: I just think it needs pointed out that .NET 2.0 and 3.0 will not contain these extensions. That's not to say it's not a correct answer, just not *always* correct.

Comment: @EBrown If people need to know that LINQ is .NET 3.5+ specific, your comment now exists to say that.  (Not that I think every single answer on SO that uses LINQ needs such a clarification, but whatever.)

Comment: I guess my example doesn't exactly align with what I was actually doing. Instead of taking until a condition is met, I want to ignore until the condition is met. I could do that with `First` or `FirstOrDefault` I suppose, I just don't like using First and then exception handling as flow control if no condition is met. Or in the case of `FirstOrDefault` checking if it isn't null. I guess I am just lazy that way :p